# AngualrJS nest Promise.all in Promise only return the first

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise

Thanks in advance. I am new and stuck in AngularJs promise.
The original code is:

```
$scope.fillInRO = function (data){
  var defer = $q.defer();
  $scope.receive_order = data.receive_order;
  var orders = _.map(data.receive_order.purchase_orders,function (value) {
    return {purchase_order:value};
  });
  $scope.fillInPOInitial(orders).then(
    function (){
      defer.resolve();
    }
  )
  return defer.promise;
}
```

And now I need to add another Promise.all

```
let promises = ids.map((id,index) => {
        PurchaseOrderFactory.getPurchaseOrder(id,store_id).then(function(res){
        $scope.receive_order.receive_order_items[index].receive_order_item.display_unit = res.purchase_items[index].display_unit
      })
    })
```

Through console.log, I know that the res is:

```
res = {
  purchase_items:[
    {display_unit: "kg"},
    {display_unit: "g"},
  ]
}
```

Before the request, the left value likes:

```
$scope.receive_order.receive_order_items = [
  {receive_order_item:{display_unit: null}},
  {receive_order_item:{display_unit: null}},
]
```

After the request,the value likes:

```
$scope.receive_order.receive_order_items = [
  {receive_order_item:{display_unit: "kg"}},
  {receive_order_item:{display_unit: null}},
]
```

But what I want is this:

```
$scope.receive_order.receive_order_items = [
  {receive_order_item:{display_unit: "kg"}},
  {receive_order_item:{display_unit: "g"}},   // here the diff
]
```

I have no idea how to correctly nest the promise.all in promise, I tried to do this:

```
  $q.all(promises).then(() =>{
    $scope.fillInPOInitial(orders).then(
      function (){
        defer.resolve()
      }
    )
  })
```

It seems make no difference, I still get the second value as null:

```
$scope.receive_order.receive_order_items = [
  {receive_order_item:{display_unit: "kg"}},
  {receive_order_item:{display_unit: null}},
]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I wonder if the error is somewhere in the call to `ids.map` - something smells off about using the index of the purchase order ID in the `ids` array as the index of the element in `purchase_items` in the response. You might need another loop if there are multiple purchase items per purchase order

Comment: Thanks! You solved my problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @mzulch, I find out there is nothing wrong with the AngularJs Promise. The error is in the call to ids.map
Add another loop and the problem solved:

```
  let promises = ids.map((id) => {
    PurchaseOrderFactory.getPurchaseOrder(id,store_id).then(function(res){
      res.purchase_items.map((purchase_item, index) => {
        data.receive_order.receive_order_items[index].receive_order_item.display_unit = purchase_item.display_unit
      })
    })
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

promises are not returned in the promises array, you are accessing values before promises are resolved so you don't get proper values.

```
let promises = ids.map((id,index) => {
         return PurchaseOrderFactory.getPurchaseOrder(id,store_id).then(function(res){
        $scope.receive_order.receive_order_items[index].receive_order_item.display_unit = res.purchase_items[index].display_unit
      })
    })
```

Then pass it to `$q.all(promises )`

Comment: @T.Judy return the value as well as the Promise: `return res.purchase_items[index].display_unit;`